# Postgres trigger that will insert a row into another table before it's deleted

Tags: postgresql, triggers, backup

I have a table (entry_table) filled with various geographic location data currently used by clients for our front end Web feature service. If a user deleted their entry in the WFS it is deleted in our postgres database. I would like to create a trigger that will run an INSERT command to copy the row(roughly 25 columns of data) to a second table(historical_entry_table) so if the entries are needed again in the future they can be easily retrieved.

Here's what I have working so far. I'm new to Triggers so I know the syntax is off. Not sure where to go from here. Im running postgres 8.4

In the table :

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE DELETE 
    ON entry_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_backup_row
```

The Function itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO historical_entry_table (col1, col2, etc) values (OLD.col1, OLD.col2, OL
RETURN NULL:

END;
$BODY$
```

Answer (score 3):

I will put a working example here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
INSERT INTO PCIcards_backup (MODEL, SUBSYSTEM_DEVICE, ADAPTER, MAPPING) values (NEW.MODEL, NEW.SUBSYSTEM_DEVICE, NEW.ADAPTER, NEW.MAPPING);
    RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$     
   language PLPGSQL
```

As you can see, you only need to set the language at the end of a file with param `PLPGSQL` because SQL cannot return triggers.

Answer (score 0):

you have just about got it.  your code here, updated :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row()
    RETURN trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO historical_entry_table (col1, col2, etc) values (OLD.col1, OLD.col2, OLD.etc);
    END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: I keep getting a syntac error pointing to RETURN. Checked and found out it needs to be RETURNS. Now it's saying Error: no language specififed

Comment: Tried adding LANGUAGE SQL but now I'm just getting a syntax error around trigger.

Comment: can you update your question with the current code that is getting the errors?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the correct version of the last answer:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_backup_row()
  RETURN trigger 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO historical_entry_table (col1, col2, etc) values (OLD.col1, OLD.col2, OLD.etc);
    RETURN new;
  END;
$$
```